# Bootstrap - Adding a pixel border to the active link on a menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm styling my navigation menu but I'm having some trouble. On mobile mode, I have home selected, and gallery is hovered, as per the image below.

[image]

However, I want there to be a 1 pixel border running between them. I have the following CSS:

```
/* Small Devices, Tablets */
@media only screen and (max-width: 766px) {
.collapsing, .in {background-color: #transparent;  border: 1px; border-color: #7A292A;}
.collapsing .in ul li a {color: #DEE0A3!important;}
.collapsing ul li a:hover, .in ul li a:hover {color: #9D343D!important; border: 1px; border-color: #7A292A;}
.collapsing ul li a:focus, .in ul li a:focus {background-color: #000 !important;}
}
```

But it's not working. Any ideas? I think I want a 1px border at the bottom of the current active navigation link, which I thought was the focus link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your HTML markup apply id on the active li and in css media rules target the li#id and apply border-bottom: 1px solid #7A292A;

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li id="active">Home</li>
    <li>Gallery</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
li#active{ border-bottom: 1px solid #7A292A;}
```

Note: Make sure you are viewing at resolution according to your css media rule.

Comment: This worked but I still don't understand _why_ it worked. For reference, I already had a class in the HTML markup for my active link, so I changed the CSS to `li.active`, which worked... but I've still got no idea why. Could you perhaps explain in a little more detail?

Comment: If it worked kindly  accept my answer. The possible reason it is not working can be the css specificity, there can be a specific css rule declared to over-ride your formating. Use the dev tools to figure out the issue. I think you should read this article https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Answer (score 0):

Add this and see if that works :

```
 .collapsing ul li a:active, .in ul li a:active {border-bottom: 1px solid #000 !important;}
```